# routerlink not working if mapcontainer is imported

Tags: angular, here-api

I am trying to import Here maps into one of our webpage.

```
    this.map = new H.Map(<HTMLElement> document.getElementById("mapContainer),
                         this.mapTypes.normal.map);
    let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));
```

On adding above line **a** tag does not work. On click of hyperlink does not take to me to new page. But works fine if I try to right click hyperlink and open in new tab.

```
<a *ngFor="let s of getSzValues(z.zones)" [ngClass]='active' href="/Detail/SZ" routerLink="/Detail/{{s[0]}}"> {{s[1]}}</a>
```

Not able to narrow down root cause. Any reference or pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Can you please add some more details to understand the issue better. Though the map and behaviour imported correctly, there are no variables associated inside <a> tag which assures the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the `*ngFor="let s of getSzValues(z.zones)"` expression in `<a>` tag. getSzValues() was being called again and again on mouse events.

Issue resolved after updating expression to fetch values from an object instead of making function call like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let key of z.subzones.keys()">
     <a routerLink="/Detail/{{ key }}">  {{z.subzones.get(key)}}</a>
</div>
```

@HEREDeveloperSupport  Thanks for responding.